# Problems with setting up govendor

Tags: go, govendor

I installed go1.8 and I am trying to use govendor for a project but it seems I am doing something wrong. The error says that I need to check my $GOPATH, but it is already set. Is it set to the wrong path?

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/rsimari/Go   

bash-3.2$ govendor init
Error: Missing GOPATH. Check your environment variable GOPATH.
bash-3.2$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/rsimari/Go
bash-3.2$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/rsimari/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-
map=/var/folders/_3/kx93r31s2l97vj436m8vdndc0000gn/T/go-
build687682041=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Comment: is GOPATH exported?

Comment: in my .bashrc I set GOPATH=... should I do export GOPATH=... instead?

Comment: Yes, you need to export a variable for other processes to use it. If you look at your GOPATH, it's not the same as what `go env` is reporting.

Comment: thanks for the help. that solved it!